# How to join and keep only latest rows in SQL (Bigquery)

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm using Bigquery. My dataset looks like the following. Basically, I started with an event table where a row is only added when data is updated. I exploded this table into the below by cross joining to a calendar table where my_date >= event_date. The problem I'm having now is when there are two event_dates per my_date (per tenancy_id), I only want to end up with the row for the latest one. (In this example, that means I want to DROP rows 4 & 12). What's the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use row_number() window function to get the latest row per my_date and tenancy_id.

```
 create table yourtable (Row int, my_date date, event_date date, tenancy_ld int, rent_period varchar(100), rent_amount int, tenancy_start_date date, tenancy_end_date date);

 insert into yourtable values(1,    '6/29/2021',    '6/29/2021', 1109,  'FORTN IGHTLY', 67794   ,'03/15/21','8/28/2021');
 insert into yourtable values(2,    '6/29/2021',    '6/29/2021', 1110,  'MONTHLY',      224364  ,'02/14/21','3/14/2022');
 insert into yourtable values(3,    '6/28/2021',    '6/28/2021', 1111,  'FORTN IGHTLY', 70000   ,'02/27/21','4/20/2022');
 insert into yourtable values(4,    '6/29/2021',    '6/28/2021', 1111,  'FORTN IGHTLY', 70000   ,'02/27/21','4/20/2022');
 insert into yourtable values(5,    '6/29/2021',    '6/29/2021', 1111,  'FORTN IGHTLY', 77056   ,'02/27/21','4/20/2022');
 insert into yourtable values(6,    '6/29/2021',    '6/29/2021', 1112,  'WEEKLY',       32830   ,'10/17/20','12/22/2021');
 insert into yourtable values(7,    '6/29/2021',    '6/29/2021', 1113,  'WEEKLY',       73620   ,'07/17/20','2/3/2022');
 insert into yourtable values(8,    '6/25/2021',    '6/25/2021', 1114,  'WEEKLY',       136     ,'09/19/20','4/26/2022');
 insert into yourtable values(9,    '6/26/2021',    '6/25/2021', 1114,  'WEEKLY',       136     ,'09/19/20','4/26/2022');
 insert into yourtable values(10,'6/27/2021',   '6/25/2021', 1114,  'WEEKLY',       136     ,'09/19/20','4/26/2022');
 insert into yourtable values(11,'6/28/2021',   '6/25/2021', 1114,  'WEEKLY',       136     ,'09/19/20','4/26/2022');
 insert into yourtable values(12,'6/29/2021',   '6/25/2021', 1114,  'WEEKLY',       136     ,'09/19/20','4/26/2022');
 insert into yourtable values(13,'6/29/2021',   '6/29/2021', 1114,  'FORTN IGHTLY', 136552  ,'09/19/20','4/26/2022');
```

Query:

```
 with cte as
 (
    select my_date, event_date, tenancy_ld, rent_period, rent_amount, 
    tenancy_start_date, tenancy_end_date, row_number()over(partition by tenancy_ld, 
    my_date order by event_date desc) rnk
    from yourtable
 )
 select my_date, event_date, tenancy_ld, rent_period, rent_amount, 
    tenancy_start_date, tenancy_end_date from cte where rnk=1
```

Output:

| my_date | event_date | tenancy_ld | rent_period | rent_amount | tenancy_start_date | tenancy_end_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-06-29 | 2021-06-29 | 1109 | FORTN IGHTLY | 67794 | 2021-03-15 | 2021-08-28 |
| 2021-06-29 | 2021-06-29 | 1110 | MONTHLY | 224364 | 2021-02-14 | 2022-03-14 |
| 2021-06-28 | 2021-06-28 | 1111 | FORTN IGHTLY | 70000 | 2021-02-27 | 2022-04-20 |
| 2021-06-29 | 2021-06-29 | 1111 | FORTN IGHTLY | 77056 | 2021-02-27 | 2022-04-20 |
| 2021-06-29 | 2021-06-29 | 1112 | WEEKLY | 32830 | 2020-10-17 | 2021-12-22 |
| 2021-06-29 | 2021-06-29 | 1113 | WEEKLY | 73620 | 2020-07-17 | 2022-02-03 |
| 2021-06-25 | 2021-06-25 | 1114 | WEEKLY | 136 | 2020-09-19 | 2022-04-26 |
| 2021-06-26 | 2021-06-25 | 1114 | WEEKLY | 136 | 2020-09-19 | 2022-04-26 |
| 2021-06-27 | 2021-06-25 | 1114 | WEEKLY | 136 | 2020-09-19 | 2022-04-26 |
| 2021-06-28 | 2021-06-25 | 1114 | WEEKLY | 136 | 2020-09-19 | 2022-04-26 |
| 2021-06-29 | 2021-06-29 | 1114 | FORTN IGHTLY | 136552 | 2020-09-19 | 2022-04-26 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=22109560edcddc1c8e083ba880a49e76)*

(It's implemented on SQL Server but should work with BigQuery)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using `qualify`:

```
select t.*
from t
where 1=1
qualify row_number() over (partition by tenancy_id, event_date
                           order by my_date desc
                          ) = 1;
```